# Multi Client Chat Program: send messages to all Clients

Tags: c, arrays

How do I print `byte_length` bytes starting at pointer `address` into a log file.

I tried this but it didnt work because dereferencing the pointer is not a string literal.

```
 FILE * userlog;
 void debug_message(int flag, void *address, int byte_length){
      for (i=0; i<byte_length; i++){
         fprintf(userlog, *((char*)address+i)));
}
```

I also tried this, but it wouldn't compile:

```
FILE * userlog;
void debug_message(int flag, void *address, int byte_length){
      for (i=0; i<byte_length; i++){
         char character[1];
         character[0]= *((char*)address+i));
         fprintf(userlog, character);
}
```

Comment: Show how you call `debug_message`. Read this: [mcve].

Comment: Maybe `fwrite (address, 1, byte_length, userlog);` instead of [`fprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/)?

Comment: BTW: the title of your question doesn't match the question.

Comment: I think you are using fprintf in a worng way. Try `fprintf(userlog, "%c", *((char*)address+i)))` [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/). I don't know if you want to use %c or %i or whatelse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fprintf` second parameter is the format specifier as you can see on [The Man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf)

If you really want to write a single char/byte `%c`

```
FILE * userlog;
void debug_message(int flag, void *address, int byte_length){
      for (i=0; i<byte_length; i++){
         char character = *((char*)address+i));
         fprintf(userlog, "%c", character);
}
```